# how to create webservice and upload my xml file into my webservice with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-services

i have created a button in html page and read a xml file , i want to upload this file into the webservice and how to create a webservice with ajax method and upload and call this file in the ajax.
 i have trying something 
my code is:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body >
  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal well">
      
      <fieldset>
          <label for="XMLFileInput"> <strong>XML</strong>
          </label>
          <input type="file" id="XMLFileInput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"
          accept=".XML">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <footer>
    <input id="getFile" type="file"/><br />
<input id="displayName" type="text" value="Enter a unique name" /><br />
<input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadFile()"/>
  </footer>

  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/read-csv.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JavaScript code is:

```js
function handleFiles(files) {
 // Check for the various File API support.
 if (window.FileReader) {
  // FileReader are supported.
  getAsText(files[0]);
 } else {
  alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
 }
}

function getAsText(fileToRead) {
 var reader = new FileReader();
 // Handle errors load
 reader.onload = loadHandler;
 reader.onerror = errorHandler;
 // Read file into memory as UTF-8      
 reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
}

function loadHandler(event) {
 var xml = event.target.result;
 processData(xml);             
}

function processData(xml) {
    var allTextLines = xml.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var lines = [];
    while (allTextLines.length) {
        lines.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));
    }
 console.log(lines);
 drawOutput(lines);
}

function errorHandler(evt) {
 if(evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
  alert("Canno't read file !");
 }
}

function drawOutput(lines){
 //Clear previous data
 alert("hi bagish");
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
 var table = document.createElement("table");
 for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var j = 0; j < lines[i].length; j++) {
   var firstNameCell = row.insertCell(-1);
   firstNameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i][j]));
  }
 }
 document.getElementById("output").appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: So, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: i want to create webservice where i  can store my uploading data

Comment: I read that, but what problem are you encountering? This isn't a code writing service where others write the code for you. Try to read up on it, and then code it. If you encounter an error or a specific problem, come back to SO and get some help.

Comment: have you any link for creating webservice for upload button

Comment: https://www.google.no/search?q=how+to+create+a+web+service&oq=how+to+create+a+web+service&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4079j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: https://www.google.no/search?ei=M2fQWsO_HaSX6AT1o7XwBA&q=how+to+upload+a+file+ajax&oq=how+to+upload+a+file+ajax&